# How to remove chinese characters in java

Tags: java

```
public class RemoveHZ                            //remove chinese characters
{
    public static String deal(String s){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
        StringBuffer se = new StringBuffer();    //store final results
        int l = sb.length();
        char c;
        for(int i=0; i<l; i++){                 
            c = sb.charAt(i);                   //get each char from string
            if(c>40 && c<127){                  //what does this mean?
                se.append(c);
            }
        }
        return new String(se);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(deal("hello你好啊"));
    }
}
```

what does the statement "if(c>40 && c<127)" mean?

Your help will be appreciated !

Comment: It means you want your ASCII code of character to be between 40 and 127, looking at a ASCII chart will help you understand what it means !

Comment: https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: you should check the char value greater than 32. `c>32` because these chars **",#,%,(** smaller than 40.

Comment: The question means that an _extract local variable_ refactoring is required to give the concept a name, say `isPrintableBasicLatinCharacter`.See your IDE docs. [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-variable.html) BTW—Java does not use ASCII. See [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class RemoveHZ {
    public static String deal(String s) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);
        StringBuffer se = new StringBuffer();    //store final results
        int l = sb.length();
        char c;
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            c = sb.charAt(i);                   //get each char from string
            if (Character.UnicodeScript.of(c) != Character.UnicodeScript.HAN) {
                se.append(c);
            }
        }
        return new String(se);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(deal("hello你好啊"));
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to use `if (!Character.isIdeographic(c))` but that would remove characters from other languages as well.

Answer (score 0):

Every character on your computer has a value. This is because a computer cannot "read" characters like a human can. These values are stored in an ASCII table for example. If you print out `c` in your code you can see the values.

The values of the chinese characters are:

- 20320
- 22909
- 21834

If you look at the ASCII table below you can see that the code that you provided filters out all the characters from `)` to `~`

[image: ASCII Table]

Answer (score 0):

This loops through each character and only appends to the `StringBuffer` if the character is between 40 and 127 on the [ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) table.

So, your print statement will only print the following characters:

> ) * + , - . / 0-9 : ; < = > ? @ A-Z ^ _ ' a-z { | } ~

Note that you're excluding `(` and `DEL` (due to starting at 41 and ending at 126)